# putting html tags value into php variable

Tags: php, html

i wanna store html tags value in a variable then send them to database, is there any way for this?

```
function start(){

$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['content'];
$src = $_POST['thumb'];

if(!empty($title) && !empty($text) && isset($_POST['sendpostbtn'])){
    try{
        include ("../config.php");
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `post` (`title`, `content` , `src`) VALUES ('$title','$text','$src')";
        $pdo->exec($sql);
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("successes")
        </script>
   <?php

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("somethings wrong")
 </script>

<?php
    }

}
?>
```

and this is my html code in the same file

```
<div class="sendpostBox">
<div class="lastpostTitle">
        <p>new post</p>
    </div>

    <form action="sendpost.php" method="post">
        <label>title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <label>src</label>
        <input type="text" name="thumb">
        <label>content</label>
        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="sendpostbtn" value="send">
    </form>
 </div>
```

I've created a form and then i want to send these data to database in the same page, i mean i don't want to open another page for this.

thanks

Comment: why dont you use empty() insted of ! = "" ?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is using one page to get details, and send them to database to store.

Comment: @TarangP i've changed it to empty. but my problem is something else. how to store these texts into database in the same page

Comment: So what is not working? You are on the right pad anyway. Should swap the insert to a prepared statement though

Comment: @DarkBee these all work out, there is something i don't understand how to code it, for example, i want to get textarea value and use it into php code, how i can do this.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST)) start();`

Comment: @DarkBee i know when and where call the function, i only want to know how to store textarea value into a variable?

Comment: .. You already did: `<textarea name="content"></textarea>`, fetch in PHP: `$text = $_POST['content'];`

Comment: i didn't pay attention to that, thanks to remind me. problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've created a form and then i want to send these data to database in
>   the same page, i mean i don't want to open another page for this.

Simply empty the form action.

Example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     ......
     ....
     ..
</form>
```

Comment: i'm wondering that how to get html tags value and use them in php code